# NoSuchElementException in Chrome. Can't find element

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to click following element:

Select a Specialty…

I used following code:

Attempt #1:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropbox_input  holder']"))).perform();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropbox_input  holder']")).click();
```

Attempt #2:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'dropbox_input') and contains(@class, 'holder')]"))).perform();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'dropbox_input') and contains(@class, 'holder')]")).click();

Attempt #3:

new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.strong div.dropbox_arrow"))).perform();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.strong div.dropbox_arrow")).click();
```

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?
Expected to see expeded drop-down, but saw new Chrome window with empty page.

Stacktrace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=30.0.1599.101)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.1,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 19 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cbd68657e133ae96672cf995890bad2ee42', time: '2013-10-18 09:51:02'
System info: host: 'ws-31', ip: '10.0.255.179', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_26'
Session ID: 3aa1fe70bb49706a5d9db19c5c388277
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.1}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=30.0.1599.101, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:404)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:101)
    at $Proxy12.findElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.findElement(EventFiringWebDriver.java:180)

Selenium version: 2.37.0
OS: Win 7
Browser: Chrome
Browser version: 30.0.1599.101 m
```

The same code works well in FireFox.

I attach screen shot to show how it looks like.[image]

Comment: Can you able to load url soon after starting Chromedriver?

Answer (score 0):

You are using ChromeDriver v2.1 with Chrome v30.

Update your ChromeDriver to the latest, version 2.1 doesn't support Chrome 30.

The effect would be that any calls, including navigation, wouldn't work, therefore any find element calls would error too.

Comment: Didn't help. Reproduced with Starting ChromeDriver (v2.4.226107) on port 23838

Comment: @DimaStar https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6510 ...why did you ask to close this if the issue is not solved? Anyway, post the code used to create the driver instance.

Comment: ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments(UtilConstants.ANDROID_USER_AGENT);
this.setDriver(new ChromeDriver(options));

Comment: I asked to close the bug because found out thtat the problem occurs before we invoke findBy this element. It occurs when we are looking for element which doesn't exist on the page. So my bug description was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, does your `xpath` or `selector` really works if you check it in, let's say, Firebug?If yes, try this option

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("selector")))
    click.perform();
```